# Getting Transformer exception while running Jmeter script

Tags: xpath, jmeter

While running my JMeter script with 3 threads, ramp-up 5 sec I am getting transformer exception. Actually in my scenario I want to click on the multiple links to the page randomly so I have used the random variable in JMeter But after running, I am getting below error, however, my XPath expression in XPath extractor looks fine.

```
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 3 threads for group Thread Group. 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 3 ramp-up 5 perThread 1666.6666 delayedStart=false 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/09/23 23:44:03 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/09/23 23:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 
2016/09/23 23:44:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3 
2016/09/23 23:44:09 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: TransformerException while processing ((//span[@class="title"]/a/@href)[$(RandomNumber)]) Expected ], but found: RandomNumber 
2016/09/23 23:44:10 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/23 23:44:10 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/23 23:44:10 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: TransformerException while processing ((//span[@class="title"]/a/@href)[$(RandomNumber)]) Expected ], but found: RandomNumber 
2016/09/23 23:44:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-3 
2016/09/23 23:44:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3 
2016/09/23 23:44:11 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: TransformerException while processing ((//span[@class="title"]/a/@href)[$(RandomNumber)]) Expected ], but found: RandomNumber 
2016/09/23 23:44:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-2 
2016/09/23 23:44:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2 
2016/09/23 23:44:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/09/23 23:44:12 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are referenced as `${RandomNumber}` - you need to use braces instead of parentheses. Alternatively you can use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function like

   ```
   ${__V(RandomNumber)}
   ```

   So you need to change your XPath query to one of the following:

   - (//span[@class="title"]/a/@href)[${RandomNumber}]
   - (//span[@class="title"]/a/@href)[${__V(RandomNumber)}]
2. Your approach seems to be fragile. I don't know how many links are at the page and how do you generate your `${RandomNumber}` variable, however I would rather go the following way:

   - Store **all** links at the page into JMeter variables like:

     ```
     link_1=http://example.com
     link_2=http://jmeter.apache.org
     ...
     link_matchNr=50
     ```
   - Use random JMeter variable from previously extracted ones where required via aforementioned [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

     ```
     ${__V(link_${__Random(1,${link_matchNr},)})}
     ```

   Demo:

   [image: JMeter Combining Variables]

   See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more information on how you can combine different JMeter Functions and Variables into a single expression.

Comment: @Bhanu Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) since it solved the problem in question.